# Check if the connection to the database is available

Tags: 8, database

I have 2 databases, the first one with Drupal and the second one with external data. In a controller I want to read data from that second database and display it.

As the external database can be available or not, **is there any method to check if the connection is available or not**?

My code is working, but if the DB is not available (or unset) I get the following error:

> Drupal\Core\Database\ConnectionNotDefinedException: The specified
> database connection is not defined: schedules in
> Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection() (line 364 of
> core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php).

Code:

```
abstract class AbstractSchedulesRepository {

  /**
   * Schedules repository target.
   */
  public const SCHEDULES_REPOSITORY_TARGET_DATABASE = 'default';

  /**
   * Schedules repository key.
   */
  public const SCHEDULES_REPOSITORY_KEY_DATABASE = 'schedules';

  /**
   * Drupal\schedules\Repository\SchedulesCache definition.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\schedules\Cache\SchedulesCache
   */
  protected $schedulesCache;

  /**
   * Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManager definition.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManager
   */
  protected $languageManager;

  /**
   * Drupal\Core\Database\Connection definition.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Database\Connection
   */
  protected $connection;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\schedules\Cache\SchedulesCache $schedulesCache
   *   Schedules cache.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManager $languageManager
   *   Language manager.
   */
  public function __construct(SchedulesCache $schedulesCache, LanguageManager $languageManager) {
    $this->schedulesCache  = $schedulesCache;
    $this->languageManager = $languageManager;
    $this->connection      = Database::getConnection(self::SCHEDULES_REPOSITORY_TARGET_DATABASE, self::SCHEDULES_REPOSITORY_KEY_DATABASE);
  }
```

Comment: Why not just catch the `ConnectionNotDefinedException`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, you are right, but I find it odd that Drupal has no method to check if the connection is available.

Comment: There’s no explicit method but It does give you a good mechanism instead - it throws exceptions if it’s not available. This is much more useful than a dedicated method, as different exceptions can be thrown to give the catcher context for why, as opposed to just yes or no. Also a `connectionAvailable` or similar method would have to actually make a connection, which costs time. As you’re already planning to make a connection, that’s wasted time. Better that you just make the connection and observe the result than cost yourself two connections by checking up front

Comment: I understand, I will check the exception, thank you very much for your answer, it helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any method to check if the connection is available or not?

If you mean class method, then no, because it wouldn’t be necessary. You can simply catch the exception, which will tell you immediately that the connection was not successful:

```
try {
  // Code using a database connection
} catch (ConnectionNotDefinedException $e) {
  // No database for you
}
```